# Windows Backup error on network share

Tags: windows, backup, active-directory

I'm trying to setup a backup schedule for my Windows Server, but I have a pretty strange issue. Whenever I set the destination for a local network share, my two drives are inaccessible, but when I backup to a harddisk, everything works fine. I've been looking at the security settings for both drives, and my admin account should have access - any ideas? :)

EDIT: The error message I get when trying to backup to a network share:

"There was a failure in updating the backup for the deleted items. Detailed error: The mounted backup volume is inaccessible. Please retry the operation."

Comment: When you say "inaccessible", what *specifically* are you seeing? What do you try to do, and what is the error message in response? Such details matter. You can **[edit]** your question to include the additional information.

Comment: Frisbee - Use the full UNC path rather than the network mapped drive for pointing to the backup location with the logic you have this job using. So `\\server\sharename\folder` rather than `X:\folder`... let me know if that helps.